# Validation of radio inputs returns a error

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Ive been stuck on this for some time now and cant figure out why the radio validation will not work on my current project, but if the form has no other functions other than the radio buttons itself then it will work. I know it has something to do with the Error.txt

any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: A jsfiddle would help to clarify this question - where does that ErrorText variable come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is your `validateForm(form)` function is expecting the form as an argument, but in your `onsubmit` handler, you don't pass the form.

Change the onsubmit so that you pass `this` to the function:

```
<form name="contactform" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, remove the `onclick` from your submit button, otherwise the validation will fire twice.

Finally, not your main issue but you refer to `x.length` which is not declared.

---

Side note: you don't need the `form.submit()` at the end of the function because you return `false` if any validation error ocurrs, therefore the form will continue to submit if all validation is OK.

Comment: Still same issue it accepts when you click the submit button after you enter a name and email, code has been updated though.

Comment: Look at my code. I use `validateForm(this)` but you used `validateForm(form)`. That's your problem, change `form` to `this` and remove the `onclick` from the submit button.

Comment: Thank you :) didn't see the x.length part