# Radio button Validation Javascript accdiently

Tags: javascript, html

It used to go but I cant find the error that's stopping it from going I was adding extra checkboxes but when I realized it was broken I tried Ctrl+Z but didnt take me far back enough :( this part no longer works " the validation for the email type, so the message that should come up is alert ( "Please choose what type of email" ); "

Comment: What do you mean make it go? It works for me. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gke8G/)

Comment: sorry I forgot to add what was actually wrong, the validation for the email type, so the message that should come up is alert ( "Please choose what type of email" );

Comment: Fiddle by @BeatAlex work for me too, it work for you too?

Comment: Please don't open a new thread for the same question again. If the answers to your old question have been unsatisfying edit this question until you get answers that actually help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388729/validation-of-radio-inputs-returns-a-error

Comment: ^ used to work using contactf for all radio's so isn't that but thanks for your input

Comment: Again it did work as I had another issue but its not the same issue, im not sure what I've actually changed that could of affected the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gke8G/1/)

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/pubfj)

Add this line to your variables:

```
var type = document.forms["contactform"]["contactf"];
```

Then do this check instead:

```
else if ( ( type[0].checked == false ) && ( type[1].checked == false ) && 
( type[2].checked == false ) && ( type[3].checked == false ))
```

Also, for your email validation, `HTML5` has `type='email'` for the inputs you can use.

Remember, just because it's (kind of) validated client side, doesn't mean someone who has enough knowledge can get around it. Make sure after, that you validate all of this server side too.

Comment: Thank you so I've must of deleted my original var type previously, lesson learned not to do coding when you have a nasty cold lol

Answer (score 0):

JS should not be used for validation because it's more of a pain than it's worth.

Observe:

Your "email validation" simply checks "does it have an @ with something before it, and a dot at least one character after the @". Well... I'm pretty sure `@@@...` is not a valid email address!

Instead: `<input type="email" />` - try typing an invalid email address in *that*!

---

Similarly:

```
<input type="radio" name="fish" value="1" required />
<input type="radio" name="fish" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="fish" value="3" />
```

Note that you only need to put "required" in one of them - you can do all of them if you want, but it's unnecessary.

Using HTML5 forms in this way, you can remove ALL validation JavaScript. Of course, you must validate on the *server*. Otherwise people can submit anything they want if they hack around a bit - JavaScript wouldn't save you from that anyway.